# hibernate: Row level security - set session context properties and pass to MS SQL

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, row-level-security

In my java based application I want to make use of RLS in MS SQL. For this, I created a security policy with a function, which expects a tenantId in the session context and filters data for this property.

Using SQL this seems to work and now I am stuck with passing the tenantId to the db, so RLS in MS SQL can filter the data, instead I am getting zero results (which seems for me that the DB doesn't recieve the tenantId from the session context).

The tenantId might change dynamically, depends on the authenticated user, so I always set the tenant_id like this:

```java
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().setProperty("TenantId", tenantId);
```

When debugging, I see that tenantId is correctly set in my java application.

My questions is:
Is `setProperty` on the session the right way to pass context/session properties to the database?

I call `setProperty` on the session, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: If your code _expects a tenant_id in the session context_ then why do you use `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().setProperty("TenantId", selectedTenantId);`? Why `TenantId` instead of `tenant_id`?

Comment: Also, SQL Server's session context has nothing to do with Hibernate's Session. In SQL Server the [session context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/session-context-transact-sql) is connection-specific, so have you considered registering a global `Session.doWork()` handler to execute `sys.sp_set_session_context` on the connection before issuing your CRUD operations?

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I updated the description a little bit to make it more clear, that I use tenantId everywhere.

Comment: @Larnu I might get wrong but the documentation doesn't mention RLS being based on a USER. You as an admionistrator decide to which properties it is relevant: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-ver16#MidTier

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I updated the description to make it clear, that the problem is not based on wrong property names. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Larnu thanks for you feedback. I'm not sure if I catch your point. I'm just having one database user for the application. For users in my application I'm using a dedicated table. So all database queries are performed by the database (application) user. When the user is authenticated and authorized in my application, I can identify the user and know its tenantId. So when a query is performec I want to pass the tenantId of the user in the session.

Comment: OK, so you're going down the ["middle-tier" application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-ver16#MidTier)? I'll fully admit, without the context, I was under the assumption you were going down the "traditional" path, of multiple `USER`s.